# Need name of the font used in the Envision logo

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image: here is logo]

I need to know the type of fonts used in this logo. I have searched in google from my known list but not find any of them useful.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a [collection of font identification resources](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try that first.

Comment: @Yisela didn't found any of the above helpful in finding the required font

Comment: Please edit your question and let us know exactly what resources you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Estilo Script: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/dstype/estilo-script/ by Dino dos Santos

The 'V' may be modified (or perhaps an alternate character).

Comment: the letter "v" comes from lower case letter "v" of regular Estilo font - http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/dstype/estilo/

Comment: yeah just got it  from a colleague thanks for helping me